# Interoperability of PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

I am distributing an installer and it will open and run a PowerShell script. The installer will be used by people who have Windows XP and up.

Am I guaranteed that this script will run/execute on all these versions of Windows? I'm looking for the similar Cross-Windows-Platform interoperability that Batch files provide.

I've heard of the error: "File cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disabled on this system" what can I do in this scenario? If a user has disabled scripts does that mean I will need to use a different language(maybe just Batch)?

Comment: PowerShell Scripts are a step higher than .bat files on windows. I would usually define a small PS script and save it and create a .dat with the ability to run it. On windows you simply use the batch files as the object to call in a scheduled task. I am unsure if you are asking if this is portable...I don't know you may have to script out admin modules on other system target.

Comment: @KendrickLamar thanks :) My main concern is, is the script going to be able to run on most users? Or is PowerShell disabled?

Comment: Ps is not guaranteed to be innstalled on xp, so you would need to be sure it was there. To get round the script execution disabled issue, you can override the execution policy when you invoke the script using the -executionpolicy argument when you run powershell.exe

Answer (score 2):

The error you're quoting is due to the default execution policy of PowerShell when it's installed. The message indicates that PowerShell *is* installed,but by default it's very restricted about what scripts may run for security purposes.

See [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176949.aspx) for more on the subject.

If you're going to use PowerShell in your installer, make it part of the system requirements for your software. I can't find anything that definitively says you can redistribute PowerShell with your application, but it's worth asking Microsoft about it.

PowerShell isn't "guaranteed" to be on any desktop OS older than Win7, but it is distributed via Microsoft Update and there's no compelling reason for users to *not* have it installed.

Answer (score 2):

If you manage this environment, then make sure that powershell is installed on the XP workstations *before* deploying the script. There is also the option of configuring group policy for powershell to enable script execution and *what type* of scripts to allow, but that's outside the scope of this question.

If you don't go the group policy route, and instead want to just run the script directly, then in your installer, call `powershell.exe` directly and pass in the following parameters:

```
powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -file \\path\to\script
```

The script path doesn't have to be a unc path if it's local, that was just an example.

Answer (score 0):

No, PowerShell scripts are not guaranteed to run on Windows XP or Windows Server 2003. Although PowerShell is [available](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968929) for these platforms, it's not installed by default.

Answer (score 0):

No, PowerShell scripts may not work, because the PowerShell isn't pre-installed on Win XP/2003.

It is included in the Management Framework for XP/2003.
For me, I suggest to use the .bat instead.